# In this code configuration should delete and add with the edited changes. But it is not adding and getting deleted

Tags: javascript, php

```
//Editing UCTM configuration
function deleteUctm(callback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        //var delRequest= $.post( "delete.php",{id : id},
        var delRequest= $.post( "delete.php",{licenseEnabled : licenseEnabled, openLicense : openLicense, id : id, ip : ip, pwd : pwd, users : users, calls : calls, multi_tenant : multi_tenant, irsf : irsf, afi : afi, tls : tls, ha : ha, attestation : attestation, verification : verification, uctm_name : uctm_name },
            function(data) {
                if(data != null && data != ""){
                    alert( data );
                }
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Unable to connect to server." );
            });
            resolve();
    })
}

function addUctm() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //var addRequest= $.post( "addUctm.php",{id : id, ip : ip, pwd : pwd, users : users, calls : calls, uctm_name : uctm_name },
        var addRequest= $.post( "addUctm.php",{ licenseEnabled : licenseEnabled, openLicense : openLicense, id : id, ip : ip, pwd : pwd, users : users, calls : calls, multi_tenant : multi_tenant, irsf : irsf, afi : afi, tls : tls, ha : ha, attestation : attestation, verification : verification, uctm_name : uctm_name },
            function(data) {
                if(data != null && data != ""){
                    if(data.includes("No license available")){
                        $("#checkBoxErr").text(data);
                    }else if(data.includes("Open License Key not")){
                        $("#openLicErr").text(data);
                    }else{
                        alert( data );
                    }
                }
                document.location.href = "globalConf.php";
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Unable to connect to server." );
            });
    }, 1000);
}
deleteUctm().then(addUctm)
}
```

This code needs to give edit values but instead adding it is getting deleted.

In above code the existing configuration should deleted and add with the same id with the edited configuration. But it is getting deleted instead of adding.

Comment: you have to give the relative address correctly , if `globalConf.php` is in the same folder of this js file , add a `/` at the beginning of your address --> `/globalConf.php` or else , provide the correct path to that file using `../` for going 1 folder back and navigating ...

Comment: no they are in make path. also i tried it is not working

Comment: @BrightFaith - _"if globalConf.php is in the same folder of this js file , add a / at the beginning"_ - Adding a slash before the URL has nothing to do with the location of the JS file. Adding a slash will just make sure it's relative from the document root, while without it, the url will be relative from the current URL.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Does the request, except from your redirect, work? Have you checked the browsers console and network tab? Is the success callback executed at all? In this code: `$.post( "delete.php",{variables }`, where are `variables` defined? Where are _any_ of the values you send defined?

Comment: document.location.href = "/globalConf.php"; i tried tis one

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes , you are right , i had to say `./fileName` instead , then it would mention to the current folder

Comment: In this same code when i click double submition config is deleting @MagnusEriksson please help me out why is deleting or give answer for to disable submit button untill process done.

Comment: Before I can help, you need to answer my questions (which is why I asked them).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in the above code configuration should delete and add with same id with edit entries but it is getting deleted. not adding configuration with the edited changes please help me out

Comment: You still haven't answered some of my questions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i gave variable in my code now, yes callback is executed. YES i debuged it by keeping alert it is not deleting all the time but in some times getting deleted. How can i set time out afer deleting th configuration.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please sir

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sir please help me out.